# Relationship between electronegativity and atomic radius

Tags: periodic-trends, electronegativity, atomic-radius

Would someone please explain in detail the relationship between the two? I understand that atomic radius is related to ionisation energy but I can't see how atomic radius may be related to electronegativity.

And it appears that they are not inversely proportional to each other, but I couldn't find any explanation for this (or for the relationship between the two) online.

I'm a sixth form student (the equivalent of high school in the US I suppose).

Comment: Sorry Clément, but I can't even answer that question because it is too complicated to go into details. You may also see in the next years that nucleophilicity and basicity are closely related to that and equally difficult to grasp.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE. They can both be explained by effective nuclear charge.  Is this a concept that was explained to you in class?